# When is a Paypal question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I made the mistake of allowing myself to get sucked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269889/creating-a-temporary-sandbox-paypal-test-account?noredirect=1#comment41214974_26269889) regarding opening an account with Paypal. The OP has picked up on Paypal's suggestion on their developer's page that support queries should be placed on Stack Overflow.

I have already explained that this is not Paypal and we can't answer questions on Paypal's operations beyond programming issues. The OP is now citing [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411517/cannot-access-paypal-developers-account-cannot-import-test-accounts?rq=1) in his own support.

Are either of these questions on topic? if not, what should we do about other similar questions that I'm sure exist?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no, they are not on-topic here.  I personally think paypal should be contacted to make their reference to SO clear, so this doesn't happen again(though it will of course).

Comment: @daedalus I saw your comments against the first question - thanks for your support.